# Motorcycle clutch longevity: Race v.s. Road

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, clutch-plate

So I realize this question may be on the line of too broad, but I think the answer(s) could be of future use to others as well, so I’m asking.

Bike: 2014 Kawasaki EX300A (296 cc I think)

At 9,000 Miles my stock clutch started to slip, so I decided to start looking at kits. The kit that I ended up getting was an EBC SRK kit that is supposed to provide aggressive friction kit “for high-power” bikes.

I figured that a strong friction clutch would provide better performance (which it did) and being that it said “for high-power” I assumed that it would last quite a while since my bike only produced 40 HP factory (as opposed to 150+ being high-power). However, I’m now at ~11,600 Miles and I’ve already noticed that my bite point has moved further out (meaning I don’t have to pull the lever far, and to engage the clutch, I have to let the lever almost all the way out). Additionally, it seems like if I hit hard and aggressive shifts, it’s lacking in delivery.

So the question is: With regard to clutches at least (and probably brakes and tires) is it commonplace for the higher-performance materials to have a shorter working life, even on weak bikes like a 300 - particularly when the driving habits are the same? Because I would expect a friction system designed for a 500lb. bike that has 150+ HP would be *much* heartier than a stock one for a 40 HP bike.

Any insights or experience is appreciated.

NOTE: There was a very noticeable increase in friction when the clutch was fresh. Several times the front tried to lift where it hadn’t before, so I do know it was better/stronger than before.

Comment: Is there some sdjustment mechanism?

Comment: The life of a clutch is HEAVILY dependant or driving style, so if you are into wheelies, fast starts etc then the life will be shorter, but if you always pull away smoothly then it will be longer...

Comment: @SolarMike that all depends on the components. If Kyle installed an "agressive friction" dry clutch meant for race bikes, a smooth driving style with a lot of clutch slipping might burn the plates right up.
Yes, they can take a lot of power, but no, it does not guarantee a longer lifespan.

Comment: @SolarMike In this case, the thing that is curious is that the wear is ~3x faster, with the same driving style and habits. I was extra gentle for the last ~300 Miles of the first clutch, but quite aggressive for the first ~8000 Miles... so that’s where the question lies. I’ll make a slight edit to reflect that.

Comment: @MadMarky a smooth driving style does not need or require a lot of clutch slipping - I would class that as a poor driving style....

Comment: @kyle_engineer you should choose friction plate compounds suitable for the task in hand - I specified and fitted a larger diameter clutch - needed a larger flywheel and it had to be re-drilled to match the new cover or pressure plate which then handled the extra power that I was transmitting. If you have chosen a "race" type clutch for general town work then that won't really match. Clutches that last longer tend to have harder linings or friction surfaces which means the action can be  less smooth.

Comment: Have heard only bad experiences about EBC, so maybe buy something else?

Comment: I did some reading online, looking at reviews for the EBC SRK kit. Seems reviews are hit or miss: either people love them or hate them. Nobody really wrote of longevity of the kit, though. Seeing as how the frictions are made with Kevlar, longevity should be good. I have two questions: 1) Did you soak the clutches prior to install? 2) What kind of oil are you using in your bike?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Mobile 1 4T (10W-40)and I soaked the plates for a few hours. Basically I put them in a bag before I started tearing down the bike and I also changed my chain and checked the valve spacing before addressing the clutch... i it had some good time I think.

Comment: Odd to hear the clutch engagement point is further out than before. Is it cable or hydraulically operated?

Comment: @Peter cable. I thought maybe cable stretch, but that would have moved the bite further in and widened it right?